# Need to try Python on OSX, but I don't have a Mac

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine, python

I need to try some Python code on OSX operating system, but I only have a Windows PC.

What is the easiest option that exist out there? An online virtual service would be great, but I am not sure if that even exists.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta have a Mac if you want to develop software for OS X or iOS.  There's no getting around that unless you're willing to go the hackintosh route.

Product recommendations are off-topic on SE sites (as are hackintosh questions), but there is a [cloud-based mac service](http://www.macincloud.com) out there.  Note, however, that I found this just now by Googling for it, so I have no knowledge of this product other than what their web site claims.

An alternative you might consider too is to just rent a real Mac.  Depending on where you live, there are stores that do this.  Maybe you could get one from a rent-to-own type store.  Or possibly a local Mac repair shop would be able to hook you up.

Answer (score 0):

The Python that is pre-installed on OS X is Python 2.7. So I believe it should execute the same as it does on any other machine running Python 2.7. If you want to be sure, however, you could run OS X in a virtual machine. Lifehacker has a great tutorial on that here: http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox